# Help with the Maximum Likelihood Estimator?

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

I'm really struggling to understand this and am trying to learn it for my upcoming exam.

The question I'm trying to do is Write down the likelihood function and then find the Maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$.

$$f_{x}(x)= \theta x^{\theta - 1} \qquad 0 \leq x \leq 1$$

So what i have is $$L(\theta : X) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \theta x^{\theta - 1} = \theta ^{n} \bigg( \prod_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \bigg)^{\theta - 1}$$

I don't really understand this and have just got to this through looking at previous examples. The bit i am stuck on is then taking the logs of this.

If anyone can help this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you write \Pi_{i=1}^n then you see $$\Pi_{i=1}^n,$$ and when you write \prod_{i=1}^n then you see $$\prod_{i=1}^n.$$  The latter is standard usage for products.  In an inline setting rather than a displayed setting, you see $\Pi_{i=1}^n$ in the former case and $\prod_{i=1}^n$ in the latter.  For the same reason, \sum rather than \Sigma is used. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you, my knowledge of writing in latex form is rather basic. I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\ell(\theta) = \log L(\theta) = \log \left( \theta^n \bigg( \prod_{i=1}^n x_i \bigg)^{\theta - 1} \right) & = \log(\theta^n) + \log \left( \left( \prod_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^{\theta-1}  \right) \\[10pt]
& = n\log\theta + (\theta - 1) \log\prod_{i=1}^n x_i.
\end{align}

You could then go on to write $\displaystyle\log\prod_{i=1}^n x_i$ as $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i$, but that won't actually help with finding the MLE, since you're concerned with this whole expression as a function of $\theta$ rather than as a function of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.

Comment: okay i get the top bit, but don't understand how the Pi can become a Sigma, I've looked at the worked solution but that was the part i was confused about the answer in the notes i get comes from differentiation but wasn't sure how my lecturer got the sigma.

Comment: The way a $\prod$ becomes a $\sum$ is this: $\log(AB) = \log A + \log B$. $\qquad$

Comment: Logarithmic rule :$log(ab) = loga +logb$.  Extending it to n we have $log(x_1x_2..x_i) = log(x_1)+log(x_2)+,,+log(x_i)$  Hence $\displaystyle\log\prod_{i=1}^n x_i$ as $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i$

Comment: Instead of $$log(x_1 x_2 .. x_i) = log(x_1) + log(x_2+..+ log(x_i),$$ you can write $$\log(x_1 x_2 \cdots x_i) = \log(x_1) + \log(x_2) + \cdots + \log(x_i),$$ coded as \log(x_1 x_2 \cdots x_i) = \log(x_1) + \log(x_2) + \cdots + \log(x_i) $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Brilliant thank you, i understand now.